# Can NoSQL injection occur between collections?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am using Node.JS and MongoDB. I am filtering all incoming data but wondering if users could potentially access data from another collection, as could be possible in an SQL injection attack (ie select from another database or table within a select statement).

Example, I have two collections

1. Movies
2. Users

If I had a function like

```js
getMovies(filter, options){
  this.movies.find(filter, options); 
}
```

Could someone somehow use either the filters or options to select all the users from the users collection, or similar?

Comment: Nope, they couldn't.

Comment: Not with `find` but perhaps if you use `aggregate`